# SQL Server: How to search the month name in MON format in a given string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have strings like 'ABCD 25Apr.xls' and i need to search and identify
the month and find the position of the first letter of the month in the given string.

Note: But I'm getting inconsistent values like 'ABCD Apr16.xls' or 'ABCD 25Apr16.xls' 'ABCD 25Apr Template(2).xls' So irrespective of the value, i get to know the position of the month.

Comment: are the months always 3 letters?

Comment: Yes. Month always have three letter in that strings

Comment: No consistent pattern means no 100% answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% fool-proof.

```
Declare @YourTable table (FileName varchar(100))
Insert into @YourTable values
('ABCD 25Mar16.xls'),
('ABCD May25.xls'),
('ABCD 15Apr16')

Select *
      ,MonthName =substring(FileName,
       CharIndex('Jan',FileName)
      +CharIndex('Feb',FileName)
      +CharIndex('Mar',FileName)
      +CharIndex('Apr',FileName)
      +CharIndex('May',FileName)
      +CharIndex('Jun',FileName)
      +CharIndex('Jul',FileName)
      +CharIndex('Aug',FileName)
      +CharIndex('Sep',FileName)
      +CharIndex('Oct',FileName)
      +CharIndex('Nov',FileName)
      +CharIndex('Dec',FileName)
      ,3)
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
FileName            MonthName
ABCD 25Mar16.xls    Mar
ABCD May25.xls      May
ABCD 15Apr16        Apr
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already have thought on this method. But looked for any better way.

Comment: No matter what, you'll end up with something that looks like this--a hard-coded list of month names playing "go fish" in a string where, hopefully, only one instance of any of those 12 sets of three letters exists.

Comment: @VigneshKiswanth Not a proud man.  I'll be watching for other answers.  Considered PatIndex() , but in my little head, this was the safest.  i.e. no false positives

Comment: @PhilipKelley My concern as well.

Comment: Might be able to improve the answer by only looking at the last 9 characters; to eliminate a few of the false positives. (4 for .xls 2 for potential year in date mix and then 3 more for month )  Does assume 3 month value will always be in last 9 positions and still not 100% but does eliminate ones that are `AJAND 25Mar.xls`

Comment: @xQbert Great point, but what if they have ...November26.xls or even Nov26 backup.xls

Comment: @JohnCappelletti He did say 3 character MON in question/comments. In the 2nd case you're right no consistent pattern means what you have is better. solution  I assumed MON would be in the last 9.

Comment: @xQbert He id, but naming conventions are are almost impossible to enforce .  This looks like user-supplied information, and I never trust the user to do what they are supposed to do.  This is why data folks like us should rule the world  :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti as always sanatize the data but i'm afraid of what would happen if the user enters `JANDEF 25 December 2016.xlsx`  would you pick out Jan or Dec? :P  Maybe we should reverse the string first and then look for the inverse of MON :P  Ok i'm just being silly now.

Comment: It's getting wild now. ;)

Comment: Obviously it's user supplied information John. Data guys are always fed up by this. Lot of stuffs to learn.

Comment: @xQbert Now, the reverse is a perfectly viable option.   Post as answer so I can upvote

Comment: @xQbert See my second answer.  Clearly I've too much time on my hands today

Comment: I look at is as providing well considered response(s).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option via a CROSS APPLY and an ad-hoc tally table

It will select the LAST "month string" within the string.  NULL if none were found

```
Declare @YourTable table (FileName varchar(100))
Insert into @YourTable values
('ABCD 25Mar16.xls'),
('ABCD May25.xls'),
('ABCD 15Apr16'),
('JANDEF 25 December 2016.xlsx'),
('daily backup.xlsx')

Select A.*
      ,Month = B.S
 From  @YourTable A
 Outer Apply (
               Select Top 1 N,S=substring(A.FileName,N,3)
                From (Select Top (len(A.FileName)) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)) From master..spt_values ) N
                Where substring(A.FileName,N,3) in ('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec')
                Order By N Desc
             ) B
```

Returns

```
FileName                        Month
ABCD 25Mar16.xls                Mar
ABCD May25.xls                  May
ABCD 15Apr16                    Apr
JANDEF 25 December 2016.xlsx    Dec
daily backup.xlsx               NULL
```

Comment: Yep.  I prefer this one!  `master..spt_values` aren't you full of surprises  and I think you planned that alias column `b.s`  we just need ms (more of the same) and PHD (piled high and deep)

Comment: @xQbert Not planned but a happy coincidence.  I was secretly hoping someone would catch that.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING to get the last 3 characters before the dot.

Comment: But the problem is, the strings are inconsistent. I'm getting values like 'ABCD 25Mar16.xls' or 'ABCD May25.xls' or 'ABCD 15Apr16' All I want to get the actual position of the month.

Comment: Then you can get the last 3 non-numeric characters before the .dot.

Answer (score 0):

Well... you are going to have to do this month by month and this is prone to error by is likely the closest you will get with your inconsistent data.

```
declare @data table (yourString varchar(64))
insert into @data
values
('ABCD 25Apr.xls'),
('ABCD Apr16.xls'),
('ABCD 25Apr Template(2).xls'),
('ABCD 25Mar.xls'),
('ABCD Mar.xls'),
('Mar.xls')


select
    yourString
    ,CHARINDEX('APR',upper(yourString),1)
from
    @data
```

You can use a case statement perhaps and account for each month...

```
select
    yourString
    ,case 
        when CHARINDEX('MAR',upper(yourString),1) > 0 then CHARINDEX('MAR',upper(yourString),1)
        when CHARINDEX('APR',upper(yourString),1) > 0 then CHARINDEX('APR',upper(yourString),1)
    end
from
    @data
```